# Unable to start Spyder after conda update/install packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I was playing around with Spyder today, and ran ONLY the following in the cmd window:

```
conda update scikit-learn

conda install matlibplot --force
```

Both ran successfully, to completion.  Now, all of a sudden, Spyder doesn't start after updating one package and installing one package.  I rebooted my machine; sitll can't gte Spyder to run.  Is there some kind of master reset, or some trick to manually get Spyder to statup?  Thanks to all.

When I reun 'spyder --reset', I think it's supposed to reset everything.  That's what I'm seeing from various posts.  When I enter that into the Anaconda prompt, all I get is 'Python has stopped working. Windows is checking for a solution'.  Then I have to close the error prompt, and that's then end of it.  There should be an easy way to fix something like this.  Literally, all I did was upgrade 2 packages.  There's no way Python can be this unstable, or fragile.

Comment: Sounds like yet another Anaconda issue. Please see the existing Anaconda questions on SO, and [issues on github](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues). Also, what versions of conda?

Comment: Yeah, I had to uninstall and re-install everything today.  After I did that, everything worked.  PITA.